# Jupyter Notebook; Cannot use columns which are not shown on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do create plot using columns on pandas. But the number of columns are many and some of the columns are not shown on Jupyter notebook. And when I use the columns which are not shown on Jupyter Notebook, the plot cannot be created corrctly. Like when I do this, `sns.pairplot(data[['col1', 'col13(cannot see on Jupyter Notebook)']])` `col1` is used as y-label instead of `col13(cannot see on Jupyter Notebook)`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try: `pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` in order to display all columns.

To reset it, type: `pandas.reset_option('display.max_columns')`.

You may change `None` to whatever number of columns you wish to have.